# Visual Studio Autocomplete Failing with Source Files which are not Part of a Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I have two source files, `game.cs` and `textEngine.cs`, both in the same namespace, but not part of a Visual Studio project or solution.

`textEngine.cs` contains a class called `Engine`, but when I try to reference any of the members of `Engine` from `game.cs` intellisense doesn't autocomplete  them.

Additionally, the 'go to definition' feature doesn't work for these members.

The files compile and run cleanly, so this is only a small problem, but an annoyance nonetheless.

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Method definition in public class Engine:

```
// start playing the currently loaded sequence
public static void StartSequence()
{
    mainTimer.AutoReset = true;
    mainTimer.Elapsed += PlaySequence;

    mainTimer.Start();

    isPlaying = true;
}
```

Method call in game.cs:

```
Engine.StartSequence();
```

Note that `Engine` is not properly highlighted and `StartSequence` was not autocompleted.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Is there a way to get Intellisense to autocomplete members of a class which is not part of a Visual Studio solution.

Comment: no, see http://superuser.com/questions/981816/enable-intellisense-for-single-cs-file-in-vs2015 . its still relevant

Comment: Thank you, I suppose I still have a lot to learn when it comes to google searching.

Comment: @user5389897, does your issue is solved or not? If it is solved, would you mind sharing your solution as a reply and mark it as answer, which will help other community members who have the same or similar issue can easier search this useful workaround. If not, please update your current issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source files that are not part of a solution apparently cannot use visual studio's auto complete.

"Visual Studio needs the project system to track which version of the .NET Framework you're targeting and which DLLs you have referenced. There is no way outside the project structure to do this."

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/981816/enable-intellisense-for-single-cs-file-in-vs2015